# next.js with http-proxy-middleware post request file upload return 400 bad reqeust immediately

Tags: nginx, axios, next.js, fetch, http-proxy-middleware

```
    const res = await axios({
      url: `http://localhost:3000/api/proxy/....`,
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "mutipart/form-data",
      },
      data: formData,
      onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
        const progress = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);
        console.log(progress);
        handleProgress(progress);
      },
      withCredentials: true,
      timeout: 900000,
      timeoutErrorMessage: "Upload failed: Request time out 15 minutes",
    });
```

server: nest.js + nginx

Another request is fine (for example, get list, post json). but file upload request return 400 bad request immediately message is nginx html

nginx error.log

```
client send invalid method while reading client request line, clinent: ip, server: empty string, request: strange string(perhaps hex code.)
```

Comment: what is you nginx configuration?

Comment: @user973254 Sorry, i can't shared config file, but i sovled my issue. By the sound of it, my problem is npm cache crash. thanks.